# Application cannot access env variables while they are available on a container level

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

node.js application, built and deployed using `docker-compose`, doesn't see any custom set variables. `console.log(process.env.VAR)` logs *undefined* to console for any of those.

Variables are set using *env_file* property in yaml file. Only *env_file* property is used. There is an *ENV* value set in Dockerfile and it's accessible by the application.

`docker exec -it <container-id> env`does return all custom values. `docker exec -it <container-id> sh` returns only those set in base image - *node-alpine* (wiped out by *exec*?).

What can be wrong with the setup?

Comment: It may help if you included the exact commands you're running to debug things, along with their output (with secrets redacted).  Also, it would be handy if you included the part of your `docker-compose.yml` file describing the problem service.

Comment: Thank you, @ctt for advice. I've found the issue, will put it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that the issue is **not** with the compose file or wrong usage of *env_file* field.
The issue was with the env file itself. It used spaces when setting values. Like this: `VAR = VAL` instead of `VAR=VAL`.
While *dotenv* npm package allows this (I've used a sample that comes with a project as a base for deployment), docker and environment don't.